# How to get the COUNT(*) based on two conditions

Tags: mysql, count

I am having trouble in getting the count(*) based on the condition.

Following is my data

```
id | user_id | key        | value
---+---------+------------+-------------------------
 1 |    3434 | first_name | Brandon
 2 |    3434 | last_name  | Johnson,Brett,Jack
 3 |    3434 | street_add | 123 main
 4 |    3434 | city       | ocean beach
 5 |    3434 | state      | Texas
```

*My query is*

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*)
from
    CUSTOMER c
where
    c.key = 'last_name'
    and
    c.value;
```

I can't pass `c.value` to the query like `c.value = Johnson,Brett,Jack` as it can change randomly each time. So it has to be generic.

I am expecting the value should be 3 it has 3 value Johnson,Brett,Jack. But I keep getting different errors each time.

**2nd question**

I also want to assign it to a variable Like below

```
DECLARE
idNumber PLS_INTEGER;

BEGIN

    Select
        COUNT(*)
    into
        idNumber
    from 
        CUSTOMER c
    where
        c.key = 'last_name'
        and
        c.value;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ID NUMBER ' || idNumber);

END;
```

Comment: `WHERE s.value` is not a valid predicate clause. If MySQL isn't giving you an error when you run it are you using a much older version of MySQL or running it with backwards-compatibility flags set?

Comment: Your query aliases the `CUSTOMER` table as `c` but then you refer to it as `s` in the same query - so these queries simply won't run at all.

Comment: `COUNT(*)` returns the **number of rows** - not the number of comma-separated values in a text column - you need to use string-processing functions for that.

Comment: typos corrected. it is 'c' not s

Comment: Are you sure you're using MySQL? `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE()` is an Oracle function, not MySQL.

Comment: Why do you have a list of multiple last names? What does that mean?

Comment: See the duplicate question I linked to. You just want to count the number of comma characters in the value, and add 1.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need something like

```
select count(*)
  from customer c
 where c.key = 'lastName'
   and c.value in ('Johnson', 'Brett', 'Jack')
```

so you can count all the `customers` with last names including `Johnson`, `Brett` and `Jack`.

With you current data model, if you want to find all people with a specific `firstName` and `lastName` you must join two instances of `customer` table as

```
select count(*)
  from customer c1
  join customer c2 on c1.user_id = c2.user_id
 where c1.key = 'firstName'
   and c2.key = 'lastName'
   and c1.value = 'John'
   and c2.value = 'Doe'
```

and it goes more complex if you need to search upon more fields.

By the way, why do you use such a data-model in an **RDBMS**? If you have an *schema-less* model, why don't you use a NoSQL database such as Mongo?

Comment: Sorry I don't want to pass c.value in ('Johnson', 'Brett', 'Jack') wanted to keep it as dynamic. As the values will be changing each time.
Need a suggestion to get count of comma-separated values in a text column

Comment: `c.value IN` won't work with a comma-separated string in `c.value`.

Comment: I see! So you want to get 2 if you pass 'Johnson,Brett' as input?

Comment: I don't want to pass anything as input in the query. Just to wanted to get the values dynamic. So want to pass & get the count that is what I am trying to achieve.